# Mixin bootstrap 3 classes - Undeclared mixin

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I'm trying to make a mixin to inherit from different bootstrap classes so in order to clarify my code.
So, instead of writing

```
<div class="row-fluid col-lg-12 page-header">
```

I would like to write something like

```
<div class="myGroup">
```

I've create a .less file:

```
@import 'bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less';


.myGroup{
    .row-fluid;      //Undeclared mixin
    .col-lg-12;      //Undeclared mixin
    .page-header;    //Loads Ok.

}
```

I'm compiling client-side. I receive "undeclared mixin".
Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: In bootstrap 3 i think you don't have a .row-fluid class, just .row or .container-fluid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Columns in Bootstrap LESS source are generated dynamically via mixins in mixins.less.
This is the reason you can't call them directly as mixins.

Anyway I think it's better practice to give `.col-lg-12` as a class to the element and not hiding it to your stylesheet. You shouldn't use `.row` and `.col-*` in same element either.

There is no such thing as `.row-fluid` in Bootstrap 3.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="page-header"> ... </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Strictly speaking Less (since v1.6.x) allows to use dynamically generated classes as mixins too but not when they are generated via quite hackish "text processing" tricks (like Bootstrap `.col-*-*` classes are). See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/78ef7353573e375ea0d9#file-24243674-less) for example.

Comment: Thanks! So it's not possible to make a kind of shortcut in order to avoid repeating n times something like "class="col-xs-6 col-md-4" with class="myMediumDiv" ?

Comment: Bootstrap provides [dedicated mixins](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-less) (e.g. `.make-*-column` etc.) you should use in this case .